# Cannot view IIS hosted website using public IP address

Tags: azure, iis, azure-virtual-machine

I have a server hosted on Azure.  I have installed IIS on this server.  I have created a basic website.  I am able to see the website when i use localhost or the private IP address.  I am not able to see the website when I use the public IP address provided by Azure.  I have not configured this server in any other way, other than to ensure that port 80 is open in the firewall.  Any ideas why can't view the website from the public IP address or a different machine?

Thank You

Comment: Do you open port 80 on the Azure NSG?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas why can't view the website from the public IP address or a
>   different machine?

If you create your VM in ARM module, We should open the port 80 on NSG(**add port 80 to inbound rules**), and **open the port 80 on windows firewall**. More information about NSG, refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal).
If you create your VM in ASM module, we should open the endpoint 80 on the old portal. More information about endpoint, refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.